# How to user biometric_storage in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, biometrics

How can i use **[biometric_Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/biometric_storage)** on flutter?

The questions i have are as follows...

1. Can it be used to validate user biometric? all i could see was **canAuthenticate**..
2. As per the documentation read,write or delete function is declared

   ```
   final myNewData = 'Hello World';
   await storageFile.write(myNewData);
   ```

But all the functions has
//for eg     write(name(key i think), content(which to be stored), promptInfo(i can't seem to assign string to it.. what should be the value here)..

and most importantly how can i validate user biometric information with this package and do read and write once the (say fingerprint) validates... Any articles regarding this?? and help would be helpful.

1. do i need to combine local_auth with this?

it also throws

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project biometric_storage".

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\\.gradle\caches\jars-8\fef84f4f98be9f93b0b593ccb1e3e207\lint-model-31.1.0.jar.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project 'biometric storage' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I was able to use the package and for read and write process..

But this gradle issue is being thrown when i try to use the latest version on Android. But on iOS it is working properly. I can't go above version 4.1.3 on android which will throw this issue..